# Move NSImage inside NSImageview

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm new to Cocoa and kinda trying to create a timer.

I'm trying to move the NSImage inside the NSImageview up or down based on a timer.

Here is how I load the image inside the NSImageview:

```
NSRect fnRect = NSMakeRect(10 + (wheelWidth / 4) - 5, 30, numbersWidth, wheelHeight);
fnImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:fnRect];
[fnImageView setImageScaling:NSScaleNone];
[fnImageView setImage:numbers];
[self addSubview:fnImageView];
```

If anyone can point me to a tutorial or give me a hint about how to do it I would appreciate it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a `NSImageView` isn't a `NSImage`. It's just used to **show** the `NSImage`.

What you want to do is probably a `NSImageView` inside a `NSView` where you could move it around.

1. Create a new `NSView`
2. Put an `NSImageView` in it
3. Move the `NSImageView` around.

Comment: What I am trying to get is effect similar to the one on the iPhone when you set the alarm clock. My image has numbers from 0-9 and i am trying to "scroll" through them as the time passes.

Comment: You want to create a `UIPickerView` on Mac OS X? I'll suggest you to to create your custom class and putting several `NSImageViews` on it (do it as I wrote in my answer), then you can response to events and move them around. It's a much better idea than do something else.

Comment: Well, i am using a custom view and loading the images on that. Dunno if this is a good solution but for rotating I used drawRect and set image setAlignmentRect, which I am updating every frame.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into CoreAnimation and working with layers.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/WhatisCoreAnimation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004689-SW1